# PowerShell String Array Pattern Matching

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell query.

I have the below 2 string arrays. What I want to be able to do is to return **only** those entries from **$RecycleBinPaths** that do not begin with **all** the entries from **$ExcludeRecycleBinsPathWildCards** (i.e. Wildcard pattern match)

```
$RecycleBinPaths = @('C:\$Recycle.Bin','D:\$RECYCLE.BIN','E:\$RECYCLE.BIN','F:\$RECYCLE.BIN','L:\$RECYCLE.BIN','M:\$RECYCLE.BIN','S:\$RECYCLE.BIN','T:\$RECYCLE.BIN')

$ExcludeRecycleBinsPathWildCards = @('C:\','F:\')
```

In the above example I want the output to be:

```
D:\$RECYCLE.BIN
E:\$RECYCLE.BIN
L:\$RECYCLE.BIN
M:\$RECYCLE.BIN
S:\$RECYCLE.BIN
T:\$RECYCLE.BIN
```

In fact **$ExcludeRecycleBinsPathWildCards** array above can contain any number of entries, not necessarily just 2 as shown above.

Are you able to help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use nested `.Where()` methods:

```
$RecycleBinPaths.Where({
  # Save path to separate variable
  $path = $_
  # Now test if _any_ string in the list of wildcards match, and then apply -not - making it resolve to true only if _none_ of the wildcards match the path
  -not $ExcludeRecycleBinsPathWildCards.Where({ $path -like "$_*" }, 'First')
})
```

Comment: Wow. You just blew my mind though I still haven't understood what your code is doing, Thanks for your help. have a nice day.

Comment: @Steve You're welcome! I've added some inline comments to help explain better. If this answer solves your problem, please consider marking it accepted by clicking the checkmark on the left :)

Comment: Does this .Where method exist on PowerShell 3 for arrays/collections? If not, is there a workaround for PS3? We have a mixture  of PS version in the estate including 3

Comment: @Steve I think it was introduced in 4.0, if memory serves me right, but I can't remember clearly - for earlier versions you can achieve the same with the `Where-Object` cmdlet

Comment: Thank you. You have taught me something new today. I never knew Where-Object could do more than just simple comparison :-) 

$RecycleBinPaths | Where-Object {$path = $_; -not ($ExcludeRecycleBinsPathWildCards | Where-Object {$path -like "$_*" })}

Answer (score 0):

Another way of looping through the items and adding to another array.

```
$RecycleBinPaths = @('C:\$Recycle.Bin','D:\$RECYCLE.BIN','E:\$RECYCLE.BIN','F:\$RECYCLE.BIN','L:\$RECYCLE.BIN','M:\$RECYCLE.BIN','S:\$RECYCLE.BIN','T:\$RECYCLE.BIN')

$ExcludeRecycleBinsPathWildCards = @('C:\','F:\')

$SelectedRecycleBinPaths = @()

foreach($rbp in $RecycleBinPaths)
{

    if(-Not ($ExcludeRecycleBinsPathWildCards -contains $rbp.ToString().Substring(0,3)))
    {
        $SelectedRecycleBinPaths += $rbp
    }

} 

$SelectedRecycleBinPaths
```

```
D:\$RECYCLE.BIN
E:\$RECYCLE.BIN
L:\$RECYCLE.BIN
M:\$RECYCLE.BIN
S:\$RECYCLE.BIN
T:\$RECYCLE.BIN
```

Comment: Thanks but your solution above assumes each of the $ExcludeRecycleBinsPathWildCards entries is exactly 3 characters long? What if it was arbitrary length?